# IR2110 parasitic issues

Tags: power-supply

I'm having issues trying to repair the power supply for a machine. For troubleshooting issues I soldered a collet IC socket to the board. When there is no input to the chip I get 50 VDC on Hin (10) 54 VDC on Vb (6) and
50 VDC on Vs (5).

When I run my simulator the normal voltages are 0 VDC on Hin (10) 15.2 VDC on Vb (6) and 0 VDC on Vs (5). When I observed the waveforms on pins 5, 6, and 7, I notice parasitic noise about 7.2 Vpp.  Do you think the noise is induced by using the IC socket? And could that be the reason for the incorrect voltages on IC 2110?

Comment: The 7.2 Vpp noise was found in the simulation?

Comment: I suppose that it's unlikely a good quality IC socket would have  effect significant to operation on a chip such as that, though the peak currents can reach amperes so it's not impossible.